# Find Youtube video duration using R

Tags: r, youtube

Is there any way to find the duration (and possibly other stats) of Youtube videos using R?  I have a list of Youtube IDs that I would like to calculate the duration of without having to manually look up each video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTML source code and a small regex help:

```
library(RCurl)
library(stringi)

url <- "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ"

# Getting HTML 
webpage <- RCurl::getURL(url)

# Extracting video length (in seconds)
stringi::stri_match_first_regex(webpage, "length_seconds\":\"(.*?)\",")[[2]]
#[1] "3118"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.